# NSURLRequest giving the correct result on iphone 5s and newer but failing on iphone 4s and 5

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, httprequest, alamofire

I've been struggling with this issue for a couple of days now but still haven't found a solution. Basically, I make a POST NSURLRequest with Alamofire and send user and password as json in the request body so that I can receive a session token in the response:

```
let mutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: path)!)
mutableURLRequest.HTTPMethod = "POST"
mutableURLRequest.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField:"Content-Type")
switch self {
case AuthenticateApp:
  let parameters = [
    "method": "login",
    "params": [
      "user": user,
      "password": pass
    ]
  ]
mutableURLRequest.HTTPBody = try! NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(parameters, options: [])
case ...
```

My problem is that the request is only successful on iphone 5s and above, while I get an error when running the same request on iphone 4s or 5:

```
{
  "error" : "Login or password was invalid.",
  "code" : 1
}
```

I have tried printing and checking multiple thing but haven't found anything that would point me to the source of the issue. I've tried the solution given in [NSHTTPURLResponse different on iPhone 5 vs 5s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25085595/nshttpurlresponse-different-on-iphone-5-vs-5s) and added the code below to the request but it didn't help:

```
mutableURLRequest.setValue("gzip", forHTTPHeaderField:"Content-Encoding")
```

I've printed the response header fields for iphone 5 and 5s and found no differences. It seems as if the server does not receive the username and password in the correct format? The username contains the "@" symbol. Could this be responsible for the problem?

**UPDATE:**

A good Samaritan from Apple's developer forum pointed me in the right direction – the requests made from a 32-bit devices are for some reason rejected by the server. I've no idea how to fix this at this point...

Comment: Could be you have different password and user. Could be that the server notices that the password/user is already used.

Comment: The user/password is the same every time. I am not logging in as a user but authorizing the app as admin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've finally managed to fix this issue. It turns out that the request body, when parsed to json, looks like this on 64-bit:

```
{
  "method": "login",
  "params": {
    "user": "user",
    "password": "password"
  }
}
```

while on 32-bit it looks like this:

```
{
  "params": {
    "password": "password",
    "user": "user"
  },
  "method": "login"
}
```

Yep, the server, for reasons unknown, requires the parameters to be listed in a specific order, otherwise it goes bananas. Thanks again, for the help.

Comment: `parameters` is a Dictionary. Dictionaries are unordered collections: no predictible order, whatever the platform is.

Comment: yet, for some reason, the backend api I'm hooking up to treats the resulting json file like an array.